# gcloud function deploy with os.subprocess: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python, deployment, subprocess, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I've got some Google Cloud Functions that I'd like to deploy from a python script using the os.subprocess.run command.  I can successfully build a statement that I can then copy-paste into my Window terminal to deploy the function(s) that looks something like this:

```
gcloud functions deploy <cloud_function_name> --runtime python37 --trigger-http --entry-point <function_in_main_to_call> --project <project_id> --timeout 540 --source "C:\\Path\\to\\code base with spaces\\project_dir"
```

Notice that the command above has spaces in the path to the local directory where the code is.

I know that subprocess.run takes a list of arguments, the first of which is the command to be executed.  Here's the code that I am using to turn the command above (that works in the terminal) into an argument list for subprocess.run:

```
deploys = [
('gcloud functions deploy <cloud_function_name> --runtime python37 '
 '--trigger-http --entry-point <function_in_main_to_call> '
 '--project {} --timeout 540 '
 '--source "{}"'.format(PROJECT_ID, 'C:\\Path\\to\\code base with spaces\\project_dir')),
]

for d in deploys:
    beg, source = d.rsplit(' --source ', 1)
    args = beg.split(' ') + ['--source'] + [source.replace('"', '\"')]    
    subprocess.run(args=args)
```

The extra list/string manipulation in args variable was an attempt to resolve the error.  When subprocess.run gets called above, I'm getting the following Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 9, in <module>
  File "C:\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py", line 403, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "C:\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py", line 707, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "C:\miniconda3\envs\myenv\lib\subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I have verified that the path/file exist.  I'm assuming it has to do with the formatting of the `--source` path string, I haven't found the solution yet. How can I deploy the Google Cloud Functions from this python script?

Comment: I think you'd build a more resilient solution using the Cloud Functions API to deploy functions rather than calling out to a shell and attempting to craft the commands there.

Answer (score 3):

On windows, try `gcloud.cmd` instead of just `gcloud`.

Comment: This made the difference for me! Wonder why this is though, there *is* a binary called `gcloud` on my PATH... In fact, if I run `where gcloud`, I get locations for both `gcloud` and `gcloud.cmd`.

Comment: This saved me so much stress. i was trying to use gcloud compute scp, and the file not found error was causing a ton of confusion. Thanks!